# AutocompleteBox validation

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have an autocomplete box in silverlight and it is bound to a collection. It is working fine. I just want it so that the user can't enter any values which are not in the collection.

For example: Collection contain a value "Head". If user Enters Headx or something other than that, a validation should be fired.

how to do this?

Regards

Arun

Comment: You Should Just Check every time SelectedItem Property is Null or Not on GotFocus

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
<Sdk:AutoCompleteBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Height="18" Width="150" 
     IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" TabIndex="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left"

     Text="{Binding ElementName=ResEdit,Path=DataContext.SelectedDemoText,Mode=TwoWay}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ResEdit,Path=DataContext.DemoList,Mode=OneWay}"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DemoTemplate}"
     ValueMemberPath="DemoCode" 
     LostFocus="AutoCompleteBox_LostFocus"
     Margin="0,0,21,0" Padding="0">
  </Sdk:AutoCompleteBox>
```

You should not use both function SelectedText and SelectedItem in autocomplete. it's a bug of AutoCompleteBox..... A better way is to set the visiblity of the textbox and AutoCompleteBox on GotFocus and LossFocus. This Way You Will Defiantly Solve You Problem

```
 private void DemoAutoComplete_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                DemoTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                DemoAutoComplete.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                DemoTextBox.Text = OCRAutoComplete.Text;

                ((DemoVM)this.DataContext).SelectedDemoText = DemoAutoComplete.Text;
            }



private void DemoTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DemoAutoComplete.Text = OctTextBox.Text;
        DemoTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        DemoAutoComplete.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        DemoAutoComplete.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to change your Binding to achieve this.

By default text properties usually update the Binding source when the control loses focus. By setting the Binding to update the source on PropertyChanged, you can implement validation with each keystroke.

Your Binding on the Text property would look something like this

```
Text="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

In your property setter you can then throw a [ValidationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationexception%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) when you deem it appropriate, or you can implement one of the validation interfaces ([INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)) and deal with it that way.

[This article is a good source of info about the complexities of data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently worked on this. My problem is solved by checking
the selected item property on the lost focus event of the autocomplete box.

```
private void autoCompleteBox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)     
{     
     if (autoCompleteBox1.SelectedItem == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(autoCompleteBox1.Text))
      {
       MessageBox.Show("Please fill in the right value");
       autoCompleteBox1.Text = "";
       autoCompleteBox1.Focus();
        }
}
```

Regards

Priya